# Delays and error messages when shutting down or resbooting. Help needed

Tags: shutdown, reboot

This a photo of the messages I get when shutting down/resetting the laptop. The whole procedure takes 4-5 minutes. It doesnt happen always but frequently

[image: 1]

It is a new computer. Dell 3410 with a SSD M.2 NVME drive and 16GB Ram.
I have Ubuntu 20.10 installed

I have dual Boot with Windows and I need the computer for my work.
I really appreciate if somebody could tell me whats wrong with it.
I tried installing MX  Linux but I get no sound there.
Could somebody tell me how to fix it or else what other distribution to use

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see there are thousand of unanswered questions.
No sense to wait hours for an answer that most likely will never come.
I think it should be better to allow to pay 3-5$ for solved questions instead of writing questions for the archive that nobody will ever answer.